# XPath Syntax to select

Tags: xpath

I want to select only the title from the following html:

```
<div class="urun">
    <div class="urun_resmi">
        <a class="urun_resmi_2703" href="/4riders-4-mevsim-ceket-siyah-sari-pmu2703" title="4RIDERS 4 MEVSİM CEKET SİYAH/SARI">
            <img src="http://WWW.MOTOMAXONLINESHOP.COM/pictures/200X-201431512318_20140313005.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="4RIDERS 4 MEVSİM CEKET SİYAH/SARI" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="urun_ismi">
        <a class="urun_ismi_2703" href="/4riders-4-mevsim-ceket-siyah-sari-pmu2703" title="4RIDERS 4 MEVSİM CEKET SİYAH/SARI">4RIDERS 4 MEVSİM CEKET SİYAH/SARI</a>
    </div>
    <div class="urun_kdvdahil_fiyati">
        <span>KDV Dahil 269,90&nbsp;TL</span>
    </div>
    <div class="urun_ikonlar">
        <a href="/4riders-4-mevsim-ceket-siyah-sari-pmu2703" title="Kampanyalı Ürün">
            <img class="kampanyali_urun_ikon" src="http://WWW.MOTOMAXONLINESHOP.COM/skin/1011/images/kampanyali.gif" alt="Kampanyalı Ürün" title="Kampanyalı Ürün" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="urun_butonlar"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

My code is:

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes((String.Format(@"//div[@class='urun']")));
```

But I need only "4RIDERS 4 MEVSİM CEKET SİYAH/SARI"

Comment: There are 2 title attributes containing text `4RIDERS 4 MEVSİM CEKET SİYAH/SARI`, which one do you want to get? The one in `<div class="urun_resmi">` or `<div class="urun_ismi">`?

Comment: I want to get in <div class="urun_ismi">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible xpath <s>assuming you want</s>(already confirmed) to get the `title` attribute from within `<div class="urun_resmi">` :

```
//div[@class='urun']/div[@class='urun_resmi']/a/@title
```

However, Html Agility Pack's `SelectNodes()` only able to return *nodes* not *attributes*, so you may need to end the xpath at `/a` and continue with selecting `title` attribute another way around :

```cs
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode
               .SelectNodes("//div[@class='urun']/div[@class='urun_resmi']/a[@title]")
               .Select(o => o.Attributes["title"].Value);
```